# Error handling when there is no error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling

I have the following code which displays the user's zipcode on the page (if you've read any of my recent questions, they all pertain to this). The zipcode usually gets displayed, except in some environments where the browser does not support geolocation. In these cases, the page displays nothing, and there are no errors logged to the console.

JS

```
function getZipCode(geolocation) {
    if (geolocation) {
        geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
           $.getJSON(
               "http://ws.geonames.org/findNearestAddressJSON?callback=?",
                {
                    lat : position.coords.latitude,
                    lng : position.coords.longitude
                },
                function (data) {
                    $(function () {
                        $('#zip').text(data.address.postalcode);
                    });
                }
            );
        });
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="zip"></div>
```

Is there any way to error handle this and show an error saying whatever when the script returns no result? I was thinking of putting text in between `#zip`, but then users whose browser do support it would see that text on load, and even though it would change, it would be a bad UX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` takes an optional `errorCallback` parameter. Use this to display the error.

Comment: What would an example be using `errorCallback`? It looks like the problem I am running into has the error of `1: User denied location`.

Comment: See http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html and search for errorCallback and positionError for examples and detailed documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Your script wont pass the if (geolocation) check.

Simply do

```
if (geolocation) {
//do stuff
}
else {
//notify user that his browser doesnt have geolocation
}
```

Comment: An example browser that doesn't work would be the browser inside of Coda. I only assumed it didn't load the zipcode because geolocation was unsupported, but after trying your suggestion, and some simple `console.log`s, it does in fact allow geolocation, but it doesn't display the zipcode. Do you have any ideas as to why this is happening and how I can error handle against this?

Comment: Do you get the position and does the JSON call return?

Comment: EDIT: I found that an example of this happening is when location services are turned off on the computer. Geolocation is supported, but location services are off.